# XML parsing in python to list and dictionary

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing an XML file with python into a list and dictionary

XML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TP name="TP03_WW35_13">
    <Class>
        <CDYN>
            <test name= "IA CDYN" PP="IA" Workload="PV">
                <Parameter name="temprature">
                    <value>100</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter name="voltages">
                    <value>0.85</value>
                    <value>1.00</value>
                    <value>1.10</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter name="Freq">
                    <value>0.8</value>
                    <value>1.2</value>
                </Parameter>
            </test>
            <test name= "GT CDYN" PP="GT" Workload="PV">
                <Parameter name="temprature">
                    <value>101</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter name="voltages">
                    <value>0.85</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter name="Freq">
                    <value>0.8</value>
                    <value>1.2</value>
                    <value>1.6</value>
                </Parameter>
            </test>
        </CDYN>
        <TDP>
            <test name="SDP" Workload="3Dmark Vantage GT1">
                <Parameter name="temprature">
                    <value>100</value>
                </Parameter>
            </test>
        </TDP>
        <Sicc>
            <test name="SA SICC" PP="SA">
                <Parameter name="temprature">
                    <value>102</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter name="voltages">
                    <value>0.85</value>
                    <value>1.00</value>
                </Parameter>
            </test>
        </Sicc>
    </Class>
</TP>
```

1. at first I wanted to take the test as a list that worked for me with the test list creator I made
2. based on that list I want to create a function that will get the test name from the list and create a dictionary and lists from its children

example output as I would like it to look:

```
TestParam { pp:IA, WL:PV, tempratures:[10,20,30],Voltages:[0.8,1.0,1.2], freq: [8,12,16]}
```

what happens is I can see that there are 3 values but only get the first one

my code:

```
def TestListCreator (root):
    TestList = []
    for Class in root.find('Class'):
        for Tests in Class:
           # TestList.append(Class.tag +Tests.attrib['name'] )
            TestList.append(Tests.attrib['name'] )
    print (TestList)
    return TestList

def main():
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    XML = ET.parse('1.xml') #parse the xml file into an elementtre
    root = XML.getroot()
    print root.tag + "=" + root.attrib['name']
    TestList = TestListCreator(root)
    print (TestList)


##    for country in root.findall(".*/CDYN/test[@name='IA CDYN']/Parameter"):
##    #for country in root.findall(".*/CDYN/test[@name=]/Parameter[@name=temprature]"):
##     rank = country.find('value').text
##     name = country.get('name')
##     print name, rank


    Vlist = []
    for country in root.findall(".*/CDYN/test[@name='IA CDYN']/Parameter"):
    #for country in root.findall(".*/CDYN/test[@name=]/Parameter[@name=temprature]"):
        #for Z in country.find('value'):
         #Vlist.append(country.attrib[])
         rank = country.find('value').text
         name = country.get('name')
         print name,rank

    print Vlist
```

Answer (score 0):

TestListCreator's iteration over Tests in Class gets elements CDYN, TDP and Sicc, which don't have name attributes.

Comment: i don't understand when running it i get the names of each test

Comment: can any one can suggest a solution ?